# Select certain Columns from multiple selected cells

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first post here. I have searched and searched for something that can help me but I'm a bit stuck.

What I'm trying to do is change the cell colour of cells in columns B:AI in rows where there are cells selected.
Example: If I select B15 & B16, and run the macro, would like cells B15:AI16 colouring a certain colour.

I have tried the below but it only works for the first cell i select.

```
Sub testMacro()

     For Each cell In Selection
        Range("B" & Selection.Row & ":AI" & Selection.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
     Next cell

End Sub
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You need to refer to your cell variable which is the one that changes in each iteration of the loop.

```
Sub testMacro()

     For Each cell In Selection
        Range("B" & cell.Row & ":AI" & cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
     Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much!